# Two variable function maximization - R code

Tags: r, function, solver

So I'm trying to maximize the likelihood function for a gamma-poisson and I've programmed it into R as the following:

```
lik<- function(x,t,a,b){    
   for(i in 1:n){
      like[i] = 
        log(gamma(a + x[i]))-log(gamma(a))
           -log(gamma(1+x[i] + x[i]*log(t[i]/b)-(a+x[i])*log(1+t[i]/b)
        }
      return(sum(like))
}
```

where x and t are the data, and I have n data rows.

I need a and b to be solved for simultaneously.  Does a built in function exist in R? Or do I need to hard code an algorithm to solve the system of equations? [I'd rather not] I know optimize() solves for 1 variable and so does fminbnd(). I'm trying to copy the behavior of FindMaximum() in mathematica. In a perfect world I'd like the code to work *something* like this:

```
optimize(f=lik, a>0, b>0, x=x, t=t, maximum=TRUE, iteration=5000)
 $maximum
    a 150
    b 6
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is probably what I want, I've just been googling for over an hr, and no one here programs in R.

Comment: (1) look at `?optim`, remembering that it *minimizes* by default (see description of `fnscale` in the help file); (2) `dnbinom` might be helpful; (3) so might `MASS::fitdistr`

Answer (score 1):

`optim'`s first argument can be a vector of parameters. So you could try something like this:

```
lik <-  function(p=c(1,1), x, t){
  # In the body of the function replace a by p[1] and b by p[2] 
}

optim(c(1,1), lik, method = c("L-BFGS-B"), x=x, t=t, control=list(fnscale=-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that ended up working out is:

```
attempt2d <- optim(
    par = c(sumx/sumt, 1), fn = lik, data = data11,
    method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1, trace=TRUE), 
    lower=0.1, upper = 170
   )
```

However my parameters run out to 170, essentially meaning that my gamma parameters are Inf.  Because gamma() hits infinity relatively quickly. And in mathematica the solutions are a=169 and b=16505, and R gets nowhere near that maxing out at 170.  The known solutions are beyond 170 in some cases any solution for this anomaly?